# Swift access array with index gives following error. Any idea why?

Tags: swift

```
let index1 = arc4random_uniform(10);

let x = array[index1];
```

The second line is giving following error

> `could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments`
>
> ```
> let x = array[index1];
>         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Comment: Pass the int value by type casting it

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to convert the index to `Int` like e.g. this:

```
let index1: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(10); // with the type of the value
let x = array[Int(index1)];
```

the `Int` is the proper index type rather than `UInt32`.

## UPDATE

if you are not quiet happy to convert the index every individual time, you can also add an extension to `Array` with defining a new subscript for your generic index type(s), e.g. such extension would look with `UInt32` like this:

```
extension Array {
    subscript (index: UInt32) -> T {
        get {
            let intIndex : Int = Int(index)
            return self[intIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

*NOTE: I have not worked out the setter here.*

Comment: Thanks holex -- just started swift today and didn't know how to typecast. I was trying (Int)index1 and it obviously was not fixing it :-)

Comment: This isn't typecasting. You're initialising a new `Int` with the UInt32 value. It's the right answer, with a slightly misleading explanation

Comment: yes, that is true, unfortunately the pure casting like `index1 as Int` is just not working in that case, I re-phrased and also have extended my answer.

Comment: The type annotation for `index1` is not necessary, just `let index1 = arc4random_uniform(10)` works as well.